# How to convert "\x09" back to tab

Tags: python, string, character-encoding, decoding

I'm reading in a file from Python that has the line:

```
#separator \x09
```

How do I convert the `\x09` into a tab character (I'm going to later use this as a delimiter)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> s = r'\x09'
>>> s.decode('unicode_escape')
u'\t'
```

Or, in Python 3.x (if you have a `str` rather than a `bytes`, because you can't `decode` a `str`):

```
>>> s = r'\x09'
>>> s.encode('unicode_escape').decode('unicode_escape')
>>> '\t'
```

See [Python Specific Encodings](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings) in the `codecs` docs for details.